# How to get PHP page in Phonegap build?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a website made with .php pages. They bring data from the database and then insert into the required areas. However I am trying to make a phonegap app with the same code. Is it possible that I call the PHP pages via AJAX from the app and then present it in the view? I don't know any other way though.

Any suggestions? I don't want to change the code to completely JavaScript because we're near the end of the project.

Comment: phonegap not support php....only a way u have to use javascript

Comment: Yes, you can call the php pages with ajax. However this means the user has to be constantly online to actually use your app, which is (at least for me) a reason not to use an app at all.

Comment: you need to make JSON api in PHP which can easily be parsed by javascript ajax. and content of the api can be displayed on page in phonegap

Comment: you also need to add API endpoint (Absolute link) in your phonegap development to get the perfect ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ahsan
What you are asking is possible, but you need to rethink you strategy.

1. Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?
2. Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005).
3. From Phonegap [FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

   > **Q: CAN YOU USE PHP/ASP/JSF/JAVA/.NET WITH PHONEGAP?**
   >
   > **A:** A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

This FAQ should also help.
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

**Addendum** 2016-03-21  This response answers the implict question.
[Convert PHP website to Phonegap application [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123390/convert-php-website-to-phonegap-application/36123800#36123800)

Comment: @Ahsan, this article might help [Convert PHP website to Phonegap application \[on hold\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123390/convert-php-website-to-phonegap-application/36123800#36123800)