# Convert PHP website to Phonegap application

Tags: php, cordova

Is it possible to convert a PHP web application to a phonegap android application. If yes, what will be the easiest method for doing it..?

Comment: Possible? Anything is possible! This question is too broad.

Comment: yes, by rewriting it

Comment: Too broad, but I answered anyway because this is sooo popular question

Answer (score 3):

## From the [Phonegap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

> **Q: CAN YOU USE PHP/ASP/JSF/JAVA/.NET WITH PHONEGAP?**
>
> A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

1. To convert PHP pages to HTML pages, remove all references to PHP and the server. All services (including MYSQL) will be on the backend (via jquery or equivalent).
2. Insert **placeholders** into those places on the webpage that you want to insert data.
3. Convert, or replicate, your supporting PHP system into a [REST API](https://www.google.com/search?q=rest+api) system.
4. Use JQuery or equivalent to (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to communicate with backend services.
5. Insert Server responses (via JQuery) into the **placeholders**.

**NOTE:** Best practice is to store all assest (javascript, css, fonts, images, etc.) on the mobile. You can also use storageLocal, SQLite, or IndexedDB to store some data locally. Server services belong on the server - it is best practice not to talk to the SQL server directly. (But many people do it the dangerous way by talking SQL over the Internet - not best practice.)

Any question? please ask at an approriate forum. Here is [a list](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/cordova-phonegap-forums.md). I recommend [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)